# Looping thru 2D array using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have several designs, and each design has several variables.

Using VBA code, I want to loop thru each design, and assign variables to each of the indices of the one design.
I'm having a hard time getting the array dim statement correct, and correctly calling the nth variable of each design. 
I've shown VBA code here that uses a message box to display if I am getting the right value from each j loop, and each design.

Any help?

```
Dim Design(0 To 9) As Variant

Sub main

Design(1) = Array(4,6,2,1)
Design(2) = Array(8,2,6,9)

For i = 1 To 2
   For j = 1 to 4
     MsgBox (Design(i)(j-1))
   Next j
Next i

End sub
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: The code I show doesn't work.  What is the correct Dim statement, and correct MsgBox statement, or correct way to dimension the arrays?

Comment: Do you feel it's not already correct?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work.

Comment: Your code is not creating a *2-D* array.  It is creating an array of arrays.  Each element of `Design` is itself an array.

Comment: I suggest you read up on understanding how arrays work in VBA, particularly multi-dimensional arrays. You can find good information in [this article](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/) and [this one](https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/17455/multidimensional-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

Wow, my apologies.  I've been trying for WEEKS to get this to work, and in formatting it for this question, it FINALLY worked!   Code is good as is.

Comment: As was mentioned already, what you have is a *jagged array* (an array of arrays). A 2D array would be declared like `Dim stuff(0 To 99, 0 To 9)`, and then you could do 
`stuff(i, j) = x` and `MsgBox stuff(i, j)`.